# Can't sign up on Careers.stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When trying to sign up, I can't get past entering my location!
It keeps saying it can't make sense of my location.

Comment: What is your location?

Comment: We have a bug introduced by some work being done with the geo filters.  This will be fixed shortly.

Comment: We currently have released some fixes on our end but are not out of the woods just yet.  We are also now resolving the last of the issues with our geocoding provider.  Once a few more of the problems are ironed out, we will give some more details about how we intend to decouple our services from our geocoding provider.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let's close \[jobs\] questions!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377689/lets-close-jobs-questions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed.  Let us know if you still see the problem.