# Cannot create profile on careers: We can't make sense of that location

Tags: bug, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t sign up on Careers.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155574/cant-sign-up-on-careers-stackoverflow)

Having logged in via Google, I am presented with this page: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/create

I cannot find a value to satisfy the location field.  The hint says "City, State, Country, Zip/Postal Code".  These are just some of the things I've tried:

```
Newark, DE, USA, 19702
Newark, DE, US, 19702
Newark, DE, United States, 19702
Newark, DE, United States of America, 19702
Newark, Delaware, US, 19702
Newark, Delaware, USA, 19702
Newark, DE
Newark, DE, 19702
Newark, DE 19702
19702
```

I even tried my full street address.  Everything I've tried results in "Hmm, we can't make sense of that location" or "Sorry, we couldn't make sense of that location. Try again?".  As this field appears to be required, I cannot proceed.

Comment: @TimStone I believe you are correct; I will note that I did search for this issue, and check a dozen or more of the suggested questions, before posting.  I can't determine how to close my own question as a duplicate; perhaps I don't have sufficient meta rep.

Comment: No worry, I just had the benefit of knowing the other question existed in advance.